# 'Snagit like' edit functionality in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, plugin

I am currently editing a map in Photoshop and I am looking for a way to highlight points of interests. Does anyone know if there is a Photoshop plugin that allows me to create arrows and other shapes? Something that allows me edit pictures with Snagit screen capture functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can already create arrows easily within Photoshop!

1. Start by selecting your line tool:

[image]

2. Then in the options above, select where you want to place your arrowheads:

[image]

Now you can create arrows anywhere by selecting a point and dragging it. You may want to fiddle around with the Weight of the line (it's what modifies the thickness of your arrow). You can obviously also change the color if you need to, and play around with the options until you get something like what you need.

Also, each new line will be its own layer, so if you want to get rid of one of your shapes while you record, just hide the layer by pressing the eye icon next to that layer (inside your Layers panel).